# Binding object to checkbox value in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So normal checkboxes in vuejs allows you to bind a model to it. 
When this model has the values from checkboxes pre filled, those particular checkboxes appear checked.

```
<tr v-for="user in users">
  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedUsers" v-bind:value="{ id: user.id }">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedUsers" value="{{ user.id }}">
  </td>
</tr>
```

However you don't get the same behaviour when you bind the checkbox value to an object.

Following is the snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Shad Jast",
      "email": "pfeffer.matt@yahoo.com"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Duane Metz",
      "email": "mohammad.ferry@yahoo.com"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Myah Kris",
      "email": "evolkman@hotmail.com"
    }, {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Dr. Kamron Wunsch",
      "email": "lenora95@leannon.com"
    }, {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Brendon Rogahn",
      "email": "verlie.buckridge@yahoo.com"
    }],
    selectedUsers: [{
      "id": "1"
    }, "1"]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h4>User</h4>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="user in users">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedUsers" v-bind:value="{ id: user.id }">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedUsers" value="{{ user.id }}">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <span>Selected Ids: {{ selectedUsers | json }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it the following way, please suggest better ways, if any:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Shad Jast",
      "email": "pfeffer.matt@yahoo.com"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Duane Metz",
      "email": "mohammad.ferry@yahoo.com"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Myah Kris",
      "email": "evolkman@hotmail.com"
    }, {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Dr. Kamron Wunsch",
      "email": "lenora95@leannon.com"
    }, {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Brendon Rogahn",
      "email": "verlie.buckridge@yahoo.com"
    }],
    previousUsers: [{
      "id": "2"
    }, {
      "id": "5"
    }, "1", "5"],
    updatedUsers: []

  },
  methods: {
    check: function(user_id) {
      var checked = false;
      for (i = 0; i < this.previousUsers.length; i++) {
        if (this.previousUsers[i].id == user_id) {
          this.previousUsers.splice(i, 1)
          return true
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h4>User</h4>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="user in users">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="updatedUsers" v-bind:value="{ id: user.id }" checked="{{check(user.id)}}">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="updatedUsers" value="{{ user.id }}">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <span>Selected Ids: {{ updatedUsers | json }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your answer. Or what you don't like? More importantly, what is the intended result?

Comment: I feel the binding should happen naturally as it happens with normal values in model. Why do I have to write a custom function when I am binding an object?

Comment: Good thing about open source software is that you can improve it. For now, I don't think there is a built-it way to do what you want. Personally I won't add this feature because using an object to collect a selection is not well defined in all contexts. What property would you collect in general? What if the property has a cycle? Do you keep them reactive? In my opinion you need to rethink your architecture, but if you disagree I encourage you to present your pull request to the official repository, I'm sure they will be happy.

Comment: Well I would only want some consistency here. If its doing it for normal data and not for an object that isn't consistent. And if its not there then it should be specified in their docs somewhere. Have tweeted and also posted in the forum. Lets see whats their take. Thanks anyways! cheers!

Comment: it is only id, what if you want to bind it with name too?

Comment: it was easy, I thought it was hard. Just add in this value v-bind:value="{ id: user.id, name: "user.name" }"